# "the next day" or "next day"

Tags: grammar, articles

[Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/next_1?q=next) has provided examples on the word "next".

Why is "the" omitted in

> "What do you think you'll be doing this time next year?"

while next day is preceded by "the" in

> "We had a dreadful argument, but he phoned me the next day (= the day after) to apologize."

Do we include "the" before "next"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first sentence "next" refers to a **specific** year.  An alternate for the first sentence might be:

"What do you think you'll be doing this time in 2015?"

In the second sentence "the next" refers to "the following."  An alternate for the second sentence might be:

"We had a dreadful argument, but he phoned me the following day to apologize."

similar to:

"The train was full, so we boarded the next train."